# reboot to bootcamp (xcode OSX)

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I am a bit stuck in my code, I have a gui with 1 button, and that button just needs to restart my mac to my bootcamp. Can anyone help me with this code?

Answer (score 1):

you need a helper tool with root rights that runs `/usr/sbin/bless` and then the `shutdown` (just FYI: this wont get into the appstore.)

Comment: Daij-Djan the code you give is a system call. Isn't there a "proper" way?

Comment: @BertColemont no there isnt, you call bless to set the startup disk and shutdown to reboot and all that with root rights..